# CSS full page background image is not working in IE8

Tags: css

I'm using following CSS code for full page background. It works fine in all major browser expect IE8. How can i fix it for IE ?

**CSS CODE:**

```
body {    
background: url(../images/bodyback.gif) no-repeat center center fixed !important; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;     
font-family: Ubuntu,Helvetica;
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code in your browsers .. it is working fine for me in all the browsers..

```
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body style=" 
 background:        url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Happy_smiley_face.png') no-repeat center center fixed !important; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;     
font-family: Ubuntu,Helvetica;
">

hi am working fine every where
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

.gif image format does not support for IE8. 
.PNG image format will works for IE8.